# Biodegradable material that keeps the termites away

Tags: plant-care, planting, container-gardening

Recently I came across [Groasis Growboxx](https://www.groasis.com/en/products/reforest-the-globe-with-efficient-water-use-and-a-high-survival-rate), a biodegradable coccoon that ensures maximum survival rate, and less water being used for their nurturing.

[image]

This was tested in Urulikanchan, Pune, India. The model was working fine, but the only problem that was concerning was the termites. The biodegradable substance was eaten up by the termites. Is there any other alternative which keeps the termites away and yet is biodegradable?